# Core data: Is there any way to efficiently query a model using implied relationships instead of real ones?

Tags: objective-c, ios, performance, core-data, data-modeling

Lets say I have the following kind of strange core data schema:

[image]

In this model, there are Accounts, and Activities which share a parent entity of Item. In addition there is a Relationship entity that models the relationships between objects instead of letting core data model the relationships using "real" relationships. In other words, the Relationship entity is being used as a kind of "join table."

Given this model, how can I fetch objects based on related objects? For instance, **how would I fetch all the Accounts that have an Activity that occurs today?**

There doesn't seem to be any way to do this in a single fetch request. The best thing I can think of so far is to first fetch the activities that occur today, then the relationships where the toId matches the ids of those Activities, and then finally the accounts where the id is matches the fromId in the relationships.

3 fetch requests to do this is suboptimal. We're going to need to support account and activity counts in the hundreds of thousands and doing all that fetching will potentially be really slow. It's also awkward to use NSFetchedResultsController with this kind of model.

Yes I know this isn't how Core Data likes to do things, but for a variety of reasons involving our server architecture and cross platform support we would like to use this data model and Core Data due to all the nice things it provides. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Give both your `Account` and `Activity` a relationship to `Relation`, ie. called `relations`, and set appropiate inverse relationships (called `account`/`activity`). So, all your items, including `Account` and `Activity` can have multiple "Relation"s.

To link an account to an activity, create a new `Relation` object and set its `account` and `activity` property, then add it to the `relations` set of both the account and the activity.

Now, if you want to fetch all accounts that have an activity, you fetch the `relations` property of your activity and, for all items in this set, retrieve the `account` property. It should be possible to integrate this into a single query.